# How to make my simple alert window work

Tags: php, button, alert

i'm currentrly coding in php and when i click a button the message should me Would you like to delete this entry?

This is where I'm currently at

```
<button onClick="alert('Sure to delete entry?')"><a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $row['guestbook_id'];?>">Remove Entry</a></button>
```

And sure it works. But when I press "x" to close the alert window it still deletes the entry.
How can you make a popup window that has the "Cancel" opition?

I would really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: `window.confirm('Are you sure')`?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (confirm("Your question")) { 
 // do things if OK
}
```

Use `confirm`

Click [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm) for examples

Answer (score 1):

The HTML

```
<a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $row['guestbook_id'];?>" 
    onclick="return areYouSure()">Remove Entry</a>
```

And the JS

```
function areYouSure()
{
   var con = window.confirm("Are You Sure?");
   if(con)
   {
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following JavaScript code:

```
if (confirm('Sure to delete entry?') == true) {
   //write your code here to delete
}
```